# Onclick callback with fetch method in Html language

Tags: javascript, html, rust, frontend

I have the following html code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Online Strategy</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codemirror/lib/codemirror.css">
    <script src="codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
    <script src="codemirror/addon/mode/simple.js"></script>
    <script src="codemirror/mode/rust/rust.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codemirror/theme/dracula.css">
</head>

<body>
    <iframe name="dummyframe" id="dummyframe" style="display: none;"></iframe>
    <form action='/result' method=POST target="dummyframe">
        <textarea id="editor" name="name"></textarea>
        <button onclick=GetData()>Run</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('editor'), {
            lineNumbers: true,
            lineWrapping: true,
            indentUnit: 2,
            tabsize: 2,
            indentWithTabs: 1,
            mode: "rust",
            theme: "dracula",
        });
        editor.setSize(700, 700);
        editor.scrollTo(700, 700);

        async function GetData() {
            console.log("my ssss");
            fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8081/result", { method: "POST" })
                .then((response) => {
                    var upperCase = response.json();
                    console.log("dddd");
                    // var upperCase = upperCase.toUpperCase();
                    // document.getElementById("outputText").innerHTML = upperCase;
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log("gggg");
                    setStatusMessage(response.status);
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    console.log("zzz");
                    setStatusMessage("ERROR");
                })
        }
    </script>

    <h3>INPUT</h3>
    <textarea id="inputText" placeholder="input" cols="70" rows="10" wrap="on"></textarea>
    <button onclick="MakeUpper()">Enter</button>
    <h3>OUTPUT</h3>
    <textarea id="outputText" placeholder="output" cols="70" rows="10" wrap="on" readonly></textarea>
    <script>
        function MakeUpper() {
            var upperCase = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
            var upperCase = upperCase.toUpperCase();
            document.getElementById("outputText").innerHTML = upperCase;
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

What I am trying to do is as following:

1. I input some text in the first textarea, then I click the Run button, then in url 127.0.0.1/result, will have a respone
2. I fetch the respone, and paste the body into the second textarea.

But it doesn't work as expected, it has error `404 not found`.

What am I doing wrong?

The server side is like this:

```rust
#![allow(unused_imports)]

use std::time;

use actix_web::{
    middleware, web, App, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder, Result,
    get,
    post,
    http::{
        header::{self ,ContentType},
        Method, StatusCode,
    }
};
use actix_files::Files;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .service(get_html)
            .service(show_result)
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8081))?
    .run()
    .await
}

#[get("/")]
async fn get_html() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok()
        .content_type("text/html")
        .body(include_str!("../form2.html"))
}

#[post("/result")]
async fn show_result(params: web::Form<InputCodes>) -> impl Responder {
    let mut res = format!("your input is {}, and I have got it in {:?}", params.name, time::Instant::now());
    HttpResponse::Ok()
        .content_type("text/plain")
        .body(res)
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct InputCodes {
    pub name: String
}
```

which is some rust codes. The function show_result handle the form post, and write some word into the /result webpage.

Comment: So what happens if you access `http://127.0.0.1/result` directly in the browser?

Comment: It is blank, contains nothing.

Comment: Object data doesn't have `toUpperCase` method.

Comment: Yes, I make the lines as to be comments, but the result is the same. The html console says it has error 404 not found.

Comment: You need some server to call. Can you add the server implementation?

Comment: You are calling ```/result``` API but where is the API ?

Comment: I add the server side codes above. The code maybe hard to read, but the function is simple, the function show_result handle the form post, and write some text to the /result body.

Comment: Can you try to change `fetch("/result")` to `fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8081/result")`

Comment: Also, you're `GET`ting, but your server is configured to only handle `POST` on that URL.

Comment: I just tried what you indicate, it has the same error. @kennarddh

Comment: Yes, I guess it is the problem. Besides `POST` and `GET`, what method should I choose? (I am new to html, so excuse me if it is a stupid question) @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: @dfadfdff `fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8081/result", { method: "POST" })` change method to post.

Comment: @dfadfdff Other than `POST` and `GET` you can use `PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE`, etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods.

Comment: I don't see `GetData` is being called.

Comment: @kennarddh, sorry, for easy to read, I didn't paste all the code. I just changed it to the complete code above, including the changing you mentioned. It then has new error  `400 bad Request`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use custom fetch to submit form. You don't need the `action` and `method` attribute.

```html
<form id="getData">
  <textarea id="editor" name="name"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Run</button>
</form>
```

```js
async function GetData(event) {
  // event.target is reference to the form element
  const data = new FormData(event.target); // Get all input data

  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8081/result", {
      method: "POST",
      body: data, // Send body
    })
    .then((response) => {
      var upperCase = response.json();
      console.log("dddd", upperCase);
      // var upperCase = upperCase.toUpperCase();
      // document.getElementById("outputText").innerHTML = upperCase;
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("gggg");
      setStatusMessage(response.status);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log("zzz");
      setStatusMessage("ERROR");
    })
}

const form = document.getElementById("getData")

form.addEventListener("submit", (event)=>{
  event.preventDefault()

  GetData(event)
})
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.
One more asking: When I click the Run button, the page jump to some other page. How can I just stay the original page, so I can see the console log?

Comment: I have edited the answer. I changed `onsubmit="GetData()"` to `onsubmit="GetData"`.

Comment: I just tried the changed code, it is still jumping to another page, the appeariance of which is same as the original one, but they are not exactly the same one, because the input in the first textarea has gone. And there is no custom console log anymore.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Can you try it?

Comment: I just tried that, it has the following error message:
Response { type: "basic", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/result", redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, statusText: "Bad Request", headers: Headers(3), body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }

Comment: The response from "XHR POSThttp://127.0.0.1:8081/result" shows:
Content type error.

Comment: Can you try to log `params: web::Form<InputCodes>` this

Comment: With the changed code, it seems the rust function `show_result` never get called, so it can't print the 'params'. 
 With the original codes, I printed params: `web::Form<InputCodes>` in rust terminal, it shows this:
Form(InputCodes { name: "let a = 1;" }).

Comment: I'm trying to dot this:
1. The html file has two `textarea`s, in the first one, I input some text;
2. Then I click the button, in my imagin, the text is sent to post;
3. the server function `show_result` get the text as a parameters, and handle the params and give some return object;
4. the  returned object lies in 127.0.0.1/result, then I extract the body and show it in the second textarea(from the html file).

Comment: I never used rust, so I don't really understand